# Cannot Connect to Microsoft SQL Server, System.Transactions missing?

Tags: sql-server-2008

Anyone please help. I have a deadline and I am unable to connect to any Microsoft SQL Server on my development box. Not sure what happened but all of a sudden when I attempt to connect to any Microsoft SQL Server, I get the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Transactions, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or
>   one of its dependencies. The module
>   was expected to contain an assembly
>   manifest. (System.Data)

Anyone PLEASE help! I am running Windows 7 x64 with Visual Studio 2008/2010, SQL Server Express 2008 R2

Comment: Also, I've looked in the GAC and both x86 and x64 versions of System.Transactions are there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be caused by different kinds of issues.

You probably have classes that reference this assembly but you didn't add a reference to your project.

Or it can be more complicated as an example [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2009/05/27/error-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system.transactions-version2.0.0.0-cultureneutral.aspx).

Try running `gacutil -I "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Transactions.dll"`

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear above, I'm using SQL Management Studio to attempt to connect to ANY sql server and it throws that error.

Comment: @Keith - did you check my link?

Comment: I did check your link but no luck.  I have both x64 and x86 System.Transactions dlls in my GAC.  So, for kicks, I thought I would copy them over to the GAC again to see if that would fix it.  The x86 version from c:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Transactions.dll would not allow me to copy the file over to c:\Windows\assembly.  It threw an error that it was expecting a manifest???  Also, I do not have gacutil anywhere on my computer.

Comment: @Keith - you should use `gacutil` instead of copying assembly.

Comment: I just attempted to use the gacutil that is located in c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\x64\gacutil.exe and received another error: "Failure adding assembly to the cache:  The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest."

Answer (score 0):

System.Transaction should be part of .NET framework and it should be installed in the GAC.  I suspect your update somehow removed it from the GAC.

Check to see if system.transaction is in the GAC.

Open Windows Explorer
Navigate to c:\windows\assembly
Check if System.Transaction is there
If not, you may need to reinstall the assembly into the GAC.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1145885.aspx/1?New+error+Could+not+load+file+or+assembly+